# Trying to render a bitmap through OpenGL but the bitmap is not visible

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es, android-bitmap, renderer

This is MyGLSurfaceView:

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

public final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

public MyGLRenderer getmRenderer() {
    return mRenderer;
}

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
    super(context);

    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer(context);

    // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}
}
```

And this is my Renderer:

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
private Triangle mTriangle;
private int[] textures;
Context context;
private static final float[] VERTEX_COORDINATES = new float[] {
        -1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f,
        +1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        +1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f
};

private static final float[] TEXTURE_COORDINATES = new float[] {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f
};

public MyGLRenderer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

private static final Buffer TEXCOORD_BUFFER = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEXTURE_COORDINATES.length * 4)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(TEXTURE_COORDINATES).rewind();
private static final Buffer VERTEX_BUFFER = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(VERTEX_COORDINATES.length * 4)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(VERTEX_COORDINATES).rewind();

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    Log.i("","MyGLRenderer onSurfaceCreated");
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    mTriangle = new Triangle();
    textures = new int[1];
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), 0);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    Log.i("","MyGLRenderer onDrawFrame");
    // Redraw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    mTriangle.draw();
    gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, VERTEX_BUFFER);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, TEXCOORD_BUFFER);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    Log.i("","MyGLRenderer onSurfaceChanged");
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){
    Log.i("","MyGLRenderer loadShader");

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}
}
```

Now I checked and onSurfaceCreated is being called. And after that, onDrawFrame is being called so I assume this should have drawn the bitmap for me, but why isn't it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to fix this using this tutorial, and created the Renderer from start:

```
https://blog.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-vi-textures/
```

I create a Mesh for my bitmap, and then I draw them like this:

```
   public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    Log.i("", "RENDERER onDrawFrame");
    // Clears the screen and depth buffer.
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Replace the current matrix with the identity matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // Translates 4 units into the screen.
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -1);
    // Draw our scene.
    try {
        if (root != null)
            root.draw(gl);
        if (rootSelf != null) {
            rootSelf.x = 0.35f;
            rootSelf.y = -0.1f;
            rootSelf.draw(gl);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("","error is: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

where root and rootSelf, are instances of my Mesh class

Answer (score 0):

In your OnCreate() method of MainActivity set GlSurfaceView object to contentView

```
GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new BitmapRenderer(getResources()));
    glSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    setContentView(glSurfaceView);
```